# how to make external API call with basic authentification from Symfony 4 controller?

Tags: api, symfony, request, basic-authentication, php-curl

As mentioned in the question I am trying to call this Adyen API with specific authentification credentials and passing JSON object,
Using Curl it is done like this.

```
curl https://pal-test.adyen.com/pal/servlet/Recurring/v68/disable \
-U "ws@Company.login":"Pa$$W0rd" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
  "merchantAccount": "exampleMerchantAccount",
  "shopperReference": "exampleShopperReference"
    }'
```

I tried to do this using HTTPClient Request:

```
$params = array(
        "merchantAccount" => "exampleMerchantAccount",
        "shopperReference" => "exampleShopperReference"
    );
$result = $this->client->request('POST', 'https://pal-test.adyen.com/pal/servlet/Recurring/v68/disable', $params);
```

But I still can't understand how to pass the basic authentification credentials.

Any help please .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written [in the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#authentication), add it to the parameters like this:

```php
$result = $this->client->request(
  'POST',
  'https://pal-test.adyen.com/pal/servlet/Recurring/v68/disable',
  [
   'auth_basic' => ['ws@Company.login', 'Pa$$W0rd'],
   'body' => $params,
  ]
);
```

Comment: Sorry I am new to this, what about the JSON object  ?

Comment: Does the edited answer help?

Comment: Yes it does thank you ^^